# Can I extract a number with a specific format from a column, and copy the number to a new column?

Tags: excel, join, merge, unpivot, text-extraction

I have a spreadsheet that is used for scheduling employees, and for our purposes we use a job name and number in the same cell like so:

| Employee | 1/1/22 | 1/2/22 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John A | ABC Job 21-1111 | XYZ Job 21-2222/ABC Job 21-1111 |
| Mike D | XYZ Job 21-2222 | JKL Job 21-3333 |

Sometimes we have employees going to multiple jobs in one day. With the way it's currently set up I can use power query, and then unpivot the data so that I can filter by job number, and see how many employees we had at a specific job on a certain date.

The issue is that when an employee goes to two jobs in one day, I get a count for "ABC Job 21-0101" and a separate count for "XYZ Job 21-0202/ABC Job 21-0101"

I'm looking for a way to pull the number "21-0101" and "21-0202" into a new row associated with each unpivoted record.

So I'd like it to look like this:

| Date | Employee Name | Job # |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/22 | John A | 21-1111 |
| 1/1/22 | Mike D | 21-2222 |
| 1/2/22 | John A | 21-2222 |
| 1/2/22 | John A | 21-1111 |
| 1/2/22 | Mike D | 21-3333 |

I hope the question makes sense! any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain your desired format from your input using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel/Office 365

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

***Code for Regex***
*Paste into a Blank Query and Rename it `fnRegexExtr`*

```
//see http://www.thebiccountant.com/2018/04/25/regex-in-power-bi-and-power-query-in-excel-with-java-script/
// and https://gist.github.com/Hugoberry/4948d96b45d6799c47b4b9fa1b08eadf

let   fx=(text,regex)=>
    Web.Page(
        "<script>
            var x='"&text&"';
            var y=new RegExp('"&regex&"','g');
            var b=x.match(y);
            document.write(b);
        </script>")[Data]{0}[Children]{0}[Children]{1}[Text]{0}

in
fx
```

***Main M Code***

```
let

//Read in data from Table
    //Change table name in next line to actual table name in your workbook
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],

//set the data types to text for all columns
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,
        List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each {_, type text})),

//Unpivot the columns EXCEPT for the Employee column
//  into a Date and a Value column
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Employee"}, "Date", "Value"),

//Use Regex to extract the job number as a List in the format nn-nnnn
//as written, the job number cannot be adjacent to any character in the set [A-Za-z0-9_]
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Job", each fnRegexExtr([Value], "\\b\\d\\d-\\d{4}\\b"), type text),

//expand the List column into rows
//then set the data type, remove unneeded columns, and put them in the desired order
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {{"Job", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Job"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Job", type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type1",{"Value"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"Date", "Employee", "Job"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Do you know if there is a way to split the job# from the cell solely based on the format of the number? In other words, if a cell contains "XX-XXXX". I'm asking because there are some instances where the job# is not the last value in the cell. For example we may write "ABC Job 21-1111 8AM Start" to let an employee know that the job starts at 8AM. In this case with the current solution it would return "Start" instead of the job# that I'm looking for. Thanks again!

Comment: @MarkColeman Yes, one can.  But it might be simpler to look for the sub-string that follows the word `Job` if that would also serve to identify it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't phrase the question as well as I could have. When I wrote "ABC Job" and "XYZ Job" I was using those as fillers for any text. The cell might read "University of Arizona 21-1234" or "Science Building 20-4567 8AM START" where the only "delimiter" I can think of would be the format of the number itself. There is no consistency other than the format of the number, so I believe that is the only reliable way to split the values. You did say it was possible, and you've been a huge help so far. Any chance you could point me in the right direction?

Comment: @MarkColeman Code edited to use a custom Regular Expression function to extract the job number.  Read the accompanying notes.  Also take a look at the included references to understand better, as well as doing a Search for Regular Expressions on the Internet, and here on SO, if you are not familiar with them.